# Swiftmailer - Outlook doesn't receive any mails

Tags: php, outlook, swiftmailer

So I'm trying to send out e-mails. I send one out to a Gmail, and an e-mail that's an Exchange account in Outlook.

Gmail works perfectly, but it doesn't work with the one in Outlook if I put in pictures.

Here's my code:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Thank you for registering');

                $img_one = $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('...'));
                $img_two = $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('...'));

                $text = '<html><body>';
                $text .= '<center><img src="' . $img_one . '" alt="Image" /></center>';
                $text .= '<br><br>';
                $text .= 'Thank you for submitting your personal data.<br>';
                $text .= 'You have registered yourself as a candidate in the finance sector.<br>';
                $text .= '<br>Best regards,<br><br>';
                $text .= '<img src="' . $img_two . '" alt="Image" /><br>';
                $text .= '</body></html>';

                $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.host.dk', 587, 'tls')
                    ->setUsername('x@x.x')
                    ->setPassword('***');

                $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

                $message->setFrom(array('sender@sender.dk' => 'Sender name'))
                    ->setTo(array('receiverone@gmail.com', 'receiver@mailthatsonoutlook.dk' => 'Receiver name'))
                    ->setBody($text, 'text/html');


                $logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger();
                $mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

                $result = $mailer->send($message);

                echo $logger->dump();
```

When I remove the lines the img elements, it works fine with Outlook. When I don't, nothing is happens. My log is the same whether I do it or not.

```
<< 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful 
++ Swift_SmtpTransport started
>> MAIL FROM:<x@x.dk> 
<< 250 2.1.0 Ok 
>> RCPT TO:<x@x.com> 
<< 250 2.1.5 Ok 
>> RCPT TO:<x@x.dk> 
<< 250 2.1.5 Ok 
>> DATA 
<< 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF> 
>> . 
<< 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 833ED2A2078B
```

I've looked and looked, but I can't find anything on this, and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Check your junk folder. Lots of things go in there.

Comment: Generally (at least) if it's gotten into the MTA queue, that's then out of PHP (and swiftmailers) hands as it's passed beyond the point where they have any effect. As far as they're concerned, the e-mail has sent.

Comment: Jason K - I checked that already, forgot to mention. ;)

Comment: So no solution? Seriously???? (other than creating an alternative body)